# DNS01 Challenge via AWS Route53 on AWS EKS not working

Tags: cert-manager

Followed the below instructions:

https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/route53/

Receiving an error on the challenge.

```
 Warning  PresentError  35s                 cert-manager-challenges  Error presenting challenge: failed to change Route 53 record set: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNT:assumed-role/cert-manager/1633841314544392345 is not authorized to perform: route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets on resource: arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/ZONEIDbecause no identity-based policy allows the route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets action
```

CERT-MANAGER installed via helm and added these to the values file:

```
namespace: "cert-manager"
serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a service account should be created
  create: true
  # The name of the service account to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name: "cert-manager-service-account"
  # Optional additional annotations to add to the controller's ServiceAccount 
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/cert-manager
  # Automount API credentials for a Service Account.
  # Optional additional labels to add to the controller's ServiceAccount
  # labels: {}
  automountServiceAccountToken: true  

Add SecurityContext fsgroup
securityContext:
  runAsNonRoot: true
  fsGroup: 1001
```

Created role called cert-manager and policy in AWS

The policy is shown below:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "route53:GetChange",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:route53:::change/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets",
        "route53:ListResourceRecordSets"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/ZONEID/*”
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "route53:ListHostedZonesByName",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I edited the AssumeRole as per below:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:oidc.region.amazonaws.com/id/EKS-HASH”
      },
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "oidc.eks.region.amazonaws.com/id/EKS-HASH:sub": "system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:cert-manager-service-account"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Created Kubernetes cert-manager resources via crd’s as per below:

```
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-playground
spec:
  acme:
    email: email.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-playground
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    solvers:
      - dns01:
          route53:
            region: eu-west-1
            hostedZoneID: ZONEID
            role: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:role/cert-manager
        selector:
          dnsZones:
            - “domain”

---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-playground
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  secretName: letsencrypt-playground
  commonName: hello.domain
  duration: 168h # 7d
  renewBefore: 120h # 5d
  dnsNames:
  - hello.domain
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-playground
    # We can reference ClusterIssuers by changing the kind here.
    # The default value is Issuer (i.e. a locally namespaced Issuer)
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    group: cert-manager.io
```

I am still getting access denied upon describing the challenge.
As per the below bug I removed the role from the clusterIssuer resource as it was already in the helm chart/serviceaccount but that made no difference.
https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/3079

I have also noticed that the certificate resource upon describing has an error.  I am relatively new to cert-manager and assumed the secret would be created upon applying the resource?

```
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                                       Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                                       -------
  Normal  Issuing    3m4s  cert-manager-certificates-trigger          Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
  Normal  Generated  3m3s  cert-manager-certificates-key-manager      Stored new private key in temporary Secret resource "letsencrypt-playground-2g4mq"
  Normal  Requested  3m3s  cert-manager-certificates-request-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "letsencrypt-playground-vjtpv"
```

Comment: Did you configure your EKS with an OIDC provider already?

Comment: Hi Javierlga, yeah there is already an EKS OIDC provider in place.